# JBoss jbpm-console deployment is failed

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

I am trying to install and run the Jbpm 6.2.0 Final full installer and I tried to start the Service by ant builder. while the starting jbpm-console give following Exception.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:668) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:278)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageDrivenBeanMetaData(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:244)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processBeanMetaData(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processBeanMetaData(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.processDeploymentDescriptor(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

2015-03-18 01:34:50,627 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jbpm-console.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"jbpm-console.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
2015-03-18 01:34:50,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "jbpm-console.war" (runtime-name : "jbpm-console.war")
2015-03-18 01:34:50,784 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "dashboard-builder.war" (runtime-name : "dashboard-builder.war")
2015-03-18 01:34:50,787 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"

2015-03-18 01:34:55,711 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jbpm-console.war (runtime-name: jbpm-console.war) in 4652ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start the server with the full profile.  Note that the installer should already do this automatically for you when using ant ('ant start.demo' or one of the other alternatives):
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6.2.0.Final/jbpm-installer/build.xml#L491

Answer (score -1):

I found something that could help you:

> I had the exact same problem, found that I was missing:

```
<mdb>  
      <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>  
      <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>  
</mdb>
```

> under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">`
>   in standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

link: https://developer.jboss.org/message/725587

Comment: I used that solution and now it says that failed to start because of unresolved dependencies

Comment: Hi there, how did you start the server? 
Are you using the ant script? It sounds that you are using the wrong profile. You shouldn't edit the standalone.xml file.. mostly because you should be using standalone-full.xml